solutions for $ \dot x = f(x) $, when $ \int_{-1}^{0}\frac{dx}{f(x)}\ $ diverges
I'm having difficulty with the following problem:
Considering $ \dot x = f(x) $, where $ f \in C(\mathbb{R}) $, $f(x) > 0, f(0) = 0 $.
I am given that the integral $ \int_{-1}^{0}\frac1{f(x)} dx\ $ diverges.
I'm asked to prove two things:
I) that for all points $x_0 < 0 $, there's a solution $g(t): [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R} $, with $ g(0) = x_0 $.
II) for all such solutions, $ \lim_{t\to \infty}g(t) = 0 $
I have a question: considering the domain $x \ne 0 $, dividing both sides by $f(x)$ and integrating with respect to $dt$, we can see that
$ \int \frac{dx}{f(x)}\ = t $. If we consider the improper integral, we get that the improper integral : $ \int_{-1}^{0}\frac1{f(x)} dx\ = \int_{-1}^{0}1  dt\ = 0 - (-1) = 1 $, and that is a contradiction.
But I'm doing something wrong, because I did not assume anything.
Could I receive some hints or guidance on how to solve the question?

Is $g(t)$ same as $x(t)$

Yes. My lecturer denotes the solutions as $g$, but it is $x(t)$, sorry for the confusion

What you are doing wrong is taking the same limits ($-1$ and $0$) for $t$ as for $x$.
$\infty=\int_{-1}^0\frac1{f(u)}\,du=\int_{x^{-1}(-1)}^{x^{-1}(0)}1\,dt=\lim_{u\to0}x^{-1}(u)-x^{-1}(-1).$
Here are hints for your problem: the solution $g$ to I) is defined by
$$t=\int_{x_0}^{g(t)}\frac1{f(u)}\,du,$$
and the proof of II) is obtained by letting $g(t)$ tend to $0^-$.

Hi, thanks for commenting. To make sure I understand, is I) correct by the FTOC and b/c the only t that satisfies is t=0 with $ g(0) = x_0 $?

I think you understood.
